# Error response from daemon when running Docker Compose on new Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, apple-silicon

I've got a new Mac and after installing Docker `4.14.1 (91661)` I keep getting "Error response from damon:... EOF" when running `docker-compose up`.

I've been able to download some images and run them but the current issue I am having is pulling Elasticsearch.

The error is slightly different each time I run it, for example:

```bash
git:(master) docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ elasticsearch Error                                                                                                                                                        1.5s
Error response from daemon: Head "https://docker.elastic.co/v2/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/manifests/7.16.3": EOF
git:(master) docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠴ elasticsearch Pulling                                                                                                                                                      2.5s
Get "https://docker.elastic.co/v2/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/manifests/sha256:8c679a18bafae7f4483e0058a78ca3ad0ab1da4f0289f97d0044946adb36cea7": EOF
git:(master) docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ elasticsearch Error                                                                                                                                                        1.5s
Error response from daemon: Head "https://docker.elastic.co/v2/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/manifests/7.16.3": EOF**
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: which Elasticsearch image you are using? it needs to be compatible with arm.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this issue by selecting

`Use containerd for pulling and storing images`

in the **Features in development** section in **Settings**

[image: Beta features image]